# MongoDB .NET driver: AsQueryable() is not found

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm trying to write a LINQ query to MongoDB:

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient ("");
            var db = client.GetDatabase("");
            var coll = db.GetCollection<string>("");
            var x =
                from x in coll.AsQueryable()
                select x;
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing this error:

> error CS1061: `MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<string>` does not
>   contain a definition for `AsQueryable` and no extension method
>   `AsQueryable` accepting a first argument of type
>   `MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<string>` could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

It seems that the method is there: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/81d9726449a8ff7baf254e92c17a231f40e21975/src/MongoDB.Driver/IMongoCollectionExtensions.cs#L51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, LINQ support is not in version 2.x. See [this](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver). The Officials say that there will be LINQ support soon.

As new version is completely asynchronous so they have to implement this functionality from the scratches. They will also LINQ this feature with class map.

As of now if you really want LINQ expressions then use Legacy class library as also told by Cetin Basoz. Or else you can try [this link](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/crud/reading/) to perform  asynchronous read operations. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

The API has changed in 2.x. It is available in 1.x driver (Legacy driver on NuGet). If you want to use it you would do it like:

```
var client = new MongoClient ();
var server = client.GetServer();
var db = server.GetDatabase("YourDb");
var coll = db.GetCollection<YourType>("YourCollection");
```

With the new API I haven't checked Linq at all. I already found the new fluent API to be very Linq like itself.

Answer (score 0):

This method is no more supported in 2.0.1. To use this move to 1.9.x.

Comment: Ok. So LINQ queries are not supported anymore? What's the alternatives?